# PHP - Having trouble with login with google OAuth

Tags: php, oauth, google-oauth, google-apps, google-authentication

I have implemented Google+ login functionality and used code from [9lessons.info](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/09/login-with-google-account-oauth.html). Every thing is working perfect but having one question.

When I am login with Google+ account and after redirecting to my home page, Google is also adding some data in URL string after my domain name like this:

```
AFTER REDIRECT MY URL: http://sitename.co.uk/?code=4/RdZ90SD--kGyId4-SVoKisqJ98iEj055IjBF307_9C0.AhV9POe7w1sXcp7tdiljKKa9bJhFkwI

My Domain: http://sitename.co.uk/

Code by Google: ?code=4/RdZ90SD--kGyId4-SVoKisqJ98iEj055IjBF307_9C0.AhV9POe7w1sXcp7tdiljKKa9bJhFkwI
```

[image]

Is there any setting from Google Developer Console for not to add code in URL?

Comment: Looks like information is being passed back via a get. There might be a setting somewhere to return it via a post instead?

Comment: Don you know or any idea about that?

Comment: Nope, just giving suggestions on where you might look for a solution.

Comment: I have searched on Google Developers Console for GRT/POST method but no luck.

Comment: If you are really unhappy with it, I know that the Google+ login (uses a google account) can do it without sending a GET back to the URL - but that would require a complete re-write.

Comment: That is the Authentication Code being returned by the authentication server.  It is used to get your initial refresh token an access token.  If you remove it you wont be able to get access.